# Too heavy query execution

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Database with 187840 lines .
When i execute this query i have this message  Query execution was interrupted

TOO HEAVY QUERY

```
SELECT days.day,count(U.sig_name) as number 
FROM days 
LEFT JOIN linked U ON 
    days.day = date(timestamp) 
    AND 
    U.sig_name REGEXP  "^Tester" 
GROUP BY days.day;
```

What is th solution ?

Comment: Why do you want to fetch such big data?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: The solution is to request less data...

Comment: Can you show us the tables CREATE statements? The two issues here, I guess, are the indexes and the REGEXP. Set good indices and use LIKE "Tester%" instead of REGEXP.

Comment: I want to display zoom line chart

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
select days.day, count(U.sig_name) as number
from days left join
     linked U
     on days.day = date(timestamp) AND U.sig_name REGEXP "^Tester"
group by days.day;
```

You have a problem because of the function call around `timestamp`.  You might find this version better:

```
select days.day,
       (select count(*)
        from linked u
        where u.timestamp >= days.day an du.timestamp < date_add(days.day, interval 1 day) and
              u.sig_name not like '%Tester%'
       )
from days;
```

For performance, you want a composite index on `linked(timestamp, sig_name)`.  This eliminates the outer aggregation (the aggregation uses the index instead), and allows an index to be used for the matching.

Comment: yes its better than my query if i limit days , but i have 356 days :/

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  If you want a particular range of days, just use a `where` clause on the outer query.

Comment: i use this query to display zoomline chart and i use days table because i have missing date range in table linked

Comment: @MondherSmii . . . Yes.  And this query should be doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle massive data using LIMIT:

```
$limit_size = 10000;
        $flag_done = false;

        for ($i = 1; ! $flag_done; $i++) {
            $queryString = "SELECT days.day,count(U.sig_name) as number from days left join linked U on days.day = date(timestamp)  AND U.sig_name REGEXP  "^Tester" group by days.day LIMIT $index*$limit_size, $limit_size";

            if($result = mysql_query($queryString, $db)){
                [WHAT YOU WANT TO DO WITH RESULT HERE]
            } else $flag_done = true;
        }
```